# ! Paragraph ended before \@xmultirow was complete

Tags: overleaf, arxiv

I am uploading the overleaf file on the arxiv but getting an error and I have what is the main reason technical.tex is the correct table and nothing wrong with it.

**Error**

```
LaTeX Warning: Citation `zhang2021reference' on page 6 undefined on input line
208.

(./tables/technical.tex
Runaway argument?
! Paragraph ended before \@xmultirow was complete.
<to be read again>
\par
l.6

?
! Emergency stop.
<to be read again>
\par
l.6

! ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on main.log.

[verbose]: pdflatex 'main.tex' failed.
[verbose]: Removing (La)TeX AUX file called 'main.aux' (1676271267 >= 1676271266)
[verbose]: Removing (La)TeX AUX file called 'main.out' (1676271267 >= 1676271266)
[verbose]: 'htex' is not a valid TeX format; will ignore.
[verbose]: TEXMFCNF is unset.
[verbose]: ~~~~~~~~~~~ Running tex for the first time ~~~~~~~~
[verbose]: Running: "(export HOME=/tmp PATH=/texlive/2020/bin/arch:/bin; cd /submissions/4724894/ && tex 'main.tex' < /dev/null)" 2>&1
[verbose]: This is TeX, Version 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2020) (preloaded format=tex)
(./main.tex
! Undefined control sequence.
l.1 \documentclass
[conference]{IEEEtran}
?
! Emergency stop.
l.1 \documentclass
[conference]{IEEEtran}
No pages of output.
Transcript written on main.log.

    [verbose]: tex 'main.tex' failed.
    [verbose]: We failed utterly to process the TeX file 'main.tex'
    [error]: Unable to sucessfully process tex files.
    *** AutoTeX ABORTING ***
    
    [verbose]: AutoTeX returned error: Unable to sucessfully process tex files.
    
    [verbose]: $autotex->process failed $@: $?: 0 $!: Inappropriate ioctl for device
    [verbose]: Error running AutoTeX process:
```

Comment: arxiv is using an older tex system. Does you tex file compile on overleaf if you switch to an older texlive?

Comment: This isn't enough for anyone who cannot see the source files uploaded to arXiv to go on, but I suspect Ulrike Fischer is on the right track, since this does compile fine under texlive 2022.

Comment: Try adding the `multirow.sty` from your system to your source packages. This error is complaining about a table, and that package had significant changes between texlive 2020 and 2022, particularly with regard to multi-paragraph text in that environment (which this error seems to be complaining about).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yes, I can compile on overleaf and i am using IEEEtrans template

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem with arXiv's version of `multirow.sty` being from TeXLive 2020, and your code being written with features not available in that version.

Within the next couple of weeks this will be ameliorated by an upgrade to the 2022 version, but in the meantime just include the copy of the `.sty` from your machine and the compiler will use the included file instead.

Comment: What do you mean> Do you mean that I will include multirow.sty file in my overleaf project?

Comment: No, I mean the version of it that's on your computer. If you don't have texlive installed locally, you can [download it](https://tug.org/texlive/), and you want to take the file from your computer, and upload it into your arXiv submission's main directory. Once you've done that, the compiler will use that file instead of the default.

Comment: Alternatively, use the [arXiv user support portal](http://arxiv.org/support/general_help) and contact me there with the exact submit-id and and I can take a look and see if you're missing anything else beyond that file (and if installing texlive is too hard, contact me there and I can drop in the version of the file you need).